Series with fractional part and inverses
For $(d,d')=1$ let $$d\overline d\equiv 1(d')\hspace {10mm}d'\overline {d'}\equiv 1(d).$$ For a multiplicative function $g$ (maybe even just take $g$ the identity  or $g(n)=1/n$) is there anything at all that can be said about the series
$$ \sum _{d,d'=1\atop {(d,d')=1}}^\infty \frac {g(d)g(d')}{(dd')^s}\left (\left \{ \frac {N\overline d}{d'}\right \} +\left \{ \frac {N\overline {d'}}{d}\right \} \right ).$$ I suspect that the expression in brackets has fractional part $1/dd'$, but I can't tell whether this is in $(0,1)$ or $(1,2)$.
This comes from trying to evaluate a sum of type $$\sum _{l+l'\leq X}f(l)f(l')\hspace {10mm}(\text {$f$ multiplicative, fairly simple, like $f(n)=\prod _{p|n}(1+O(1/p))$)}$$ up to an error $o(x)$ by writing $f=g\star 1$ and then writing $$\sum _{l+l'=N\atop {\mathbf d|\mathbf l}}1$$ exactly using the fractional part.

Unless I am mistaken, the parenthesised expression is equal to $1+1/(dd')$.

You are right - actually I think I needed a trickier version than what I wrote - I have an $N$ too, and have now edited the question accordingly. I think the fractional part of the parenthesis is ${ 1+1/dd'} $ but not sure when the true value is bigger or smaller than 1.  (Also thanks for looking at it!)
